# What happens when you mix Hypochlorous Acid (HClO) and Hydrogen Peroxide (H2O2) in water (H2O)

Tags: water-treatment

I currently use Hypochlorous Acid (HClO) in my plant reservoir. I really want to use Hydrogen Peroxide (H2O2) also. Is there any reason why not to use Hypochlorous Acid (HClO) and Hydrogen Peroxide (H2O2) together in water (H2O).

Comment: Could you edit your question to include the concentrations that you are talking about, and to explain what a plant reservoir is? Otherwise, the question might be closed as too broad. Also, can you edit your question to indicate what the adverse consequences are that you want to avoid (change in pH, explosion, exothermic reaction, one reagent not stable in the presence of the other)? It might be unclear what you are asking otherwise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a famous reaction to generate singlet oxygen. I am not how do you generate HOCl. If these two components (hypochlorite ion, and peroxide ion) are reacted under certain alkaline conditions, oxygen is immediately evolved with a red glow. One is left with chloride ions and water. Video link here

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vMi8kKXgshk

[image: Youtube demo of singlet oxygen]